# Changing links in Google Scholar Profile

Tags: google-scholar

I'm sorry if this has a very obvious answer, but I've looked around and haven't been able to find one.

I set up my GoogleScholar Profile and added my publications to it without a problem. So far, so good.

However, most of them are linking to publisher websites that people won't be able to access. Is there any way to change this so that the links point to, for instance, my institutional repository instead?

Clarification: The links are definitely there under the different "versions," but I'd like to have them be the FIRST link.

Comment: In addition to the accurate answers so far, it's worth pointing out that GS can take quite a while to index papers from repositories - think in months rather than days.

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be both Yes and No.

**Yes --** If your university repository articles are (also) indexed in Google Scholar, then these are absolutely citable. Now, when viewers click a particular article from your page--say "*An article on the behavior of rat after cutting its tail*"--they should be able to see two versions of the same article like the following:

[v1] An article on the behavior of rat after cutting its tail [publisher page]

[v2] An article on the behavior of rat after cutting its tail [pdf-univ. link]

**No --** If your university repository is not indexed by Google Scholar.

You can check this by searching an article from your univ. repository in Google Scholar.

Answer (score 1):

As Coder's answer states, not all databases/websites are indexed by Google Scholar. Two open access ones that are are [arXiv](https://arxiv.org) and the [Open Science Repository](http://www.open-science-repository.com). You can also use [OpenDOAR](http://www.opendoar.org/find.php) to find open access repositories that would be suitable for your work.